# how would i change jQuery idTabs to accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

i have used [jQuery idTabs](http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/) for tabs in my project, and now i need to change them to accordion when viewed from mobile devices, as the project i'm doing is responsive website.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any responsive framework?... If yes than they provide tab for mobile device. What you have to do is just add mobile class.

If no than i have ugly solution: Create two section 1) Tabs 2) Accordion. than use css media query and hide accordion by default. For mobile devices hide tab and show accordion...

Comment: hi shail, i'm not using any responsive framework, what i'm trying to do is that modify the jquery idtabs js to work as i exected. thanks

Comment: I got it what you are trying to do but problem is: When tabs generated by jquery ui, it adds so many classes in html. So you have to remove it all. I this work is panic... So you can try my suggestion... I have used this before.